# Speed up the applications of the function "cummean" on 4 vectors

Tags: r, optimization, dplyr

I have 2 vectors with the same length `x,y`. Then `x^2,y^2` are square (element-wise) of `x,y` respectively. In each iteration, I need to apply function `cummean` on `x,y,x^2,y^2`.

I would like to ask if I can speed up the process someway rather than running 4 separate operations.

```
library(dplyr)
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
y <- c(5, 5, 6)

dplyr::cummean(x)
dplyr::cummean(y)
dplyr::cummean(x^2)
dplyr::cummean(y^2)
```

Thank you so much for your suggestion!

Comment: I don't think there is enough information shared to suggest speedup. It depends on how you use them in your code. Those are 4 independent operations. You could reduce the line of code by using `lapply` i.e `lapply(list(x, y), function(x) list(cummean(x), cummean(x^2)))` but this does not give increase in speed.

Comment: I tested in Rcpp, but dplyr::cummean is already very fast so no improvement. Take care to update to dplyr v1.0.2 because [there was a bug in dplyr v1.0.0 with cummean](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5436)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could do something like:

```r
tibble(x, y) %>% 
   mutate(across(1:2, ~.x^2, .names = c("{col}^2"))) %>% 
   mutate(across(1:4, cummean, .names = "cummean_{col}"))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 8
#>       x     y `x^2` `y^2` cummean_x cummean_y `cummean_x^2` `cummean_y^2`
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
#> 1     1     5     1    25      1            5             1            25
#> 2     2     5     4    25      1            5             1            25
#> 3     3     6     9    36      1.33         5             2            25
```

And if you want the variables in the global environment rather than in a tibble you could do:

```r
tibble(x, y) %>% 
  mutate(across(1:2, ~.x^2, .names = c("{col}^2"))) %>% 
  mutate(across(1:4, cummean, .names = "cummean_{col}")) %>% 
  as.list() %>% 
  list2env(envir = globalenv())
```

Or in a function if you had to do this a lot you could do:

```
func <- function(x, y)
{
  tibble(x, y) %>% 
    mutate(across(1:2, ~.x^2, .names = c("{col}^2"))) %>% 
    mutate(across(1:4, cummean, .names = "cummean_{col}")) %>% 
    as.list() %>% 
    list2env(envir = parent.frame())
}
```

Comment: unfortunately according to `microbenchmark` extremely slow in comparison to the 4 separate operations

Comment: @Waldi I assumed the OP meant "avoid repetition of coding" rather than "improve processing speed", since they said "rather than running 4 separate operations". However, I could be wrong about that. In terms of raw processing speed, I'm guessing you can't improve much on `cummean` - which is why another reason why I assume the OP was looking for code that prevented repetition rather than a speed up. Clarification would help. Appreciate you testing though @Waldi

Comment: thanks for your feedback : let's wait for clarifications from OP on how to understand the question! And you're right, `cummean` seems unbeatable on speed.

Comment: I meant the code to increase the speed of my algorithm. As such, @Waldi is right.